# Install SiftGPU for RGBDSLAM

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After working to fix all of the fuerte bugs in RGBDSLAM, I finally got it to the point that it will launch RGBDSLAM and it shows Kinect input at the bottom. However, when I hit the space bar to run, the terminal outputs the following:

//[FATAL] [1344446005.784101274]: Can't run SiftGPU
//[FATAL] [1344446006.241891559]: SiftGPU cannot be used. Detection of keypoints failed

I have seen that SiftGPU can be disabled in the CMakeLists.txt, but I am not positive on all the steps  needed to completely disable it and use something else. When I comment it out of the file, it produces an image of the first frame and its features, but after that it gives an error saying that it cannot match the features in the next frame. Is there a way to make it run?  How do I either use SiftGPU or disable it?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40909/install-siftgpu-for-rgbdslam/) by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-09-06**:
If rgbdslam compiles, you don't need to change CMakeLists.txt.

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-03-30**:
How to disable SiftGPU in CMakeLists.txt? I am stuck at final step of installing rgbdslam_v2 with this [error](https://answers.ros.org/question/286457/catkin_make-error-no-rule-to-make-target-libg2o-needed-by-rgbdslam/?comment=287057#post-id-287057)

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsiftgpu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My suggestion is to set the parameter "matcher_type" to "FLANN".
If you have no OpenGL support, you should also rather use SURF or ORB as Sudhan says.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2013-05-15**:
@Felix Endres   i have found the file named parameter_server.cpp  and rgbdslam_sample_config.launch . both of them can set param feature detector and extractor . i am confused , what 's the difference?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-05-16**:
a "cpp"  file is program code that needs to be compiled and can then be executed. A "launch" file defines what programs to start and with what parameterization. Use the launch file.

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2013-05-16**:
@Felix Endres  thanks a lot. and what is the  function about gicp 。cna you provide some additional information to study how to use gicp ? thanks

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-05-16**:
I am not sure I understand. You could google for "generalized icp".